# Issues paths after compile Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I faced with [the same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275124/how-to-resolve-nodejs-paths-after-compiling-code-written-in-typescript)

I have next tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "newLine": "LF",
        "outDir": "./output/",
        "target": "es2015",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@src/*": ["src/*"],
            "@scripts/*": ["src/scripts/*"],
            "@helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
            "@types/*": ["src/types/*"],
            "@entity/*": ["src/types/entity/*"],
            "@enum/*": ["src/types/enum/*"],
            "@request/*": ["src/types/request/*"],
        }
    },
```

I want to pay your attention on block **paths**.

I use **"@enum/MyClass"** for import **MyClass**.
And I have absolute correct and building code. But after compile, I had js code with import path **"@enum/MyClass"** instead **"src/types/entity/MyClass"**.

How can I get js code with correct paths? Of course, I can cancel all variable-paths, but it is bad way.

Answer (score 1):

You described above the expected "paths" behaviour. This parameter is not resolving compilation process of modules mapping in your JS artefacts.

From the similar issue from official TypeScript repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866#issuecomment-246789510

> Well and to add context, "paths" is designed for use with loaders that
> allow remapping, unlike the Node.js require(). The intended behaviour
> is to allow TypeScript to resolve type information for various module
> IDs used by various loaders, not to rewrite module IDs. Basically it
> doesn't do what you thought it did. Nor should it in my opinion, it
> should only have the capability to mirror the resolution strategies of
> loaders.

So, I can suggest you to use additional popular plugins for your loader such as
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths for typescript compiler
or https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin for your webpack.